# I want to exclude multiple entries in a search with criteria

Tags: spring, jpa, criteria, predicate

I have an application with recipes.
Recipes have ingredients that themselves have aliments. I set up a filter to only recover recipes that have at least one aliment. But I'm stuck to filter the recipes to have the one that only have these aliments.

I use spring-boot with JPA. My database is mySQL.I have already try to just negate my request by writing:
    joinIngredients.get("aliment").in(aliments).not()

I try to join INNER to. without success :(

```
Recipe(recette)
|__Ingredient
   |_Aliment
```

Recipe

```
@Entity
public class Recette implements Serializable {

    //id, etc.

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.DETACH, mappedBy = "recette", orphanRemoval = true)
    private Collection<Ingredient> ingredients;
}
```

Ingredient

```
@Entity
public class Ingredient implements Serializable {

    @ManyToOne
    @JsonIgnore
    @JoinColumn(name="idRecette") 
    private Recette recette;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
    @JoinColumn(name = "idAliment")
    private Aliment aliment;
}
```

Aliment

```
@Entity
public class Aliment implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long idAliment;

    @Column(columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(40)", unique=true)
    private String nom;
}
```

Recette.repo method : The if and the else give the same thinks !!

```
public Predicate toPredicate(Root<Recette> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder) {
    query.orderBy(criteriaBuilder.asc(root.get("titre"))).distinct(true);
    List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
    //others predicates


    if (!aliments.isEmpty()) {
        Join<Recette, Ingredient> joinIngredients = root.join("ingredients", JoinType.LEFT);
        if (exclusiveAlimentsWanted) {
             List<Aliment> alimentsNotWanted = alimentSrv.findAll();
             for(Aliment aliment : aliments) {
                 alimentsNotWanted.remove(aliment);
             }
             predicates.add(
                 joinIngredients.get("aliment").in(alimentsNotWanted).not()
             );
        }else{
            predicates.add(
                joinIngredients.get("aliment").in(aliments)
            );
        };
    }

    return criteriaBuilder.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[predicates.size()])) ;
}
```

I have four recipes,

- the 1 with flour.
- the 2 with flour and eggs.
- the 3 with eggs and milk
- the 4 with flour, egg and milk.

if I just select flour, I have recipes 1, 2 and 4. OK.

if I also select "exclusiveAlimentsWanted" I just want recipe 1, but I still have recipes 1, 2 and 4. KO.

I filter directly with the predicates in building the queries for the database. (Sorry if I do not use the right words, I help Google to translate, hihi)

My application is currently little as just for my family but if it works I have many recipes can be 1,000.

Thanks

Comment: Can you give concrete example in the domain? E.g. an example Recipe, aliments and what needs to be filtered out etc. Also have you considered loading your data from the Datastore and filtering on the application level? What is the expected size of your data?

Comment: I edit my question with my answers.
I do not know if that really answers your question?